# Let A be compact and B be closed subset of A show that B is compact?

Tags: general-topology

$(i)$ - If $(O_i)_{i\in I}$ is an open cover of B

$(ii)$ - And I have the complement of $B$ is open set

I will use $(i)$ and $(ii)$ to get open cover of $A$
Then I will use the compactness of A to get the required result .
But how? 
I am becoming confused 
Please help me out

Comment: That is correct

Answer (score 1):

Let $U$ be an open cover of $B$ and consider the open cover $V$ of $A$ obtained from $U$ by adding the open set $O=A\setminus{B}$.

Since $A$ is compat, there is a finite subcover $v$ of $V$ that still covers $A$. It suffices to note that $u=v\setminus{O}$ is a finite subcover of $U$ that still covers $B$.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out 